# Select the values from two dyanamic dropdowns

Tags: javascript, java, selenium-webdriver, dropdown

I am trying to select values from the two dropdowns (currency selection) from the site https://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/ using java selenium web driver.

I also need the code to verify the conversion after the currency conversion

I have tried:

```
1. Custom XPath.
2. Normal select using select keyword.
3. Tried using mouse actions but couldn't locate. Looks like it needs javascript executor but don't know the code.
```

`org.openqa.selenium.ElementClickInterceptedException:` element click intercepted: Element `<div class="css-1wy0on6 converterform-dropdown__indicators">...</div>` is not clickable

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you're having this [Cookie Consent Disclaimer](http://ec.europa.eu/ipg/basics/legal/cookies/index_en.htm) which intercepts your input events therefore you cannot efficiently click the dropdown values.

[image]

In the [Selenium Java API](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/) your best friend is [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) class:

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 5);
```

I would recommend using [Explicit Wait](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) via the aforementioned WebDriverWait together with the [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) in order to:

1. First ensure that the cookie disclaimer is visible and can be clicked then click it:

   ```
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions
           .elementToBeClickable(
                   By.xpath("//button[contains(@class,'privacy') and contains(text(), 'OK')]")))
           .click();
   ```
2. Then do the same for the first dropdown:

   ```
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions
           .elementToBeClickable(
                   By.id("from")))
           .click();
   ```
3. And finally choose the currency of your choice by performing another click:

   ```
   wait.until(ExpectedConditions
           .elementToBeClickable(
                   By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'GBP')]")))
           .click();
   ```

   replace `GBP` with what you need as the source currency

Comment: Thank you. But both dropdowns having same div so  same custom xpath. how can we differenciate?

Comment: I got it. Thanks

Comment: @Dmitri, At step 3 how would you know whether drop down values tag name is `<span>`???? it might be be `<li>` also right?  As per input `type = hidden` how would u come to know that tag name?